# jointJS/Rappid - False displaying of source and targer arrowheads when the manhattan router used

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jointjs, rappid

I want to have a specific cell always toBack, in order to be able to put a whole graph over it, as in the picture(here this cell has a light blue background color), but my source and target arrowheads are not displayed accordingly when the link uses the Manhattan router.

[image]

The code I wrote to set this cell toBack is:

```
cell.toBack();
```

This means that this cell will always be at the lowest level of graph.

What should I do in order all transitions which are over this cell to be displayed as being just in the paper,I mean as in the following picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you use any specific router e.g. `manhattan`?

Comment: Exactly. I use manhattan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The Manhattan router used in the example is not able to find the route due to a large obstacle (light blue rectangle) covering both source and target element.

## Solution 1

1. Make sure the container element has a unique type.

   ```
   var Container = joint.dia.Element.define('ns.Container', {
     attrs: {
       rect: {
         refWidth: '100%',
         refHeight: '100%',
         stroke: 'black',
         fill: 'lightblue'
       }
     }  
   }, {
     markup: 'rect'
   });

   var container = new Container;
   container.resize(200,200);
   container.position(100, 100);
   container.addTo(graph);
   ```

   *For older versions of JointJS/Rappid*

   ```
   var Container = joint.dia.Element.extend({
     markup: 'rect',
     defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
       type: 'ns.Container',
       attrs: {
         rect: {
           'ref-width': '100%',
           'ref-height': '100%',
           'stroke': 'black',
           'fill': 'lightblue'
          }
       }
     }, joint.dia.Element.prototype.defaults)
   });
   ```
2. Instruct the Manhattan router not to consider the container element for the obstacle.

   ```
   new joint.dia.Paper({
     defaulRouter: {
       name: 'manhattan',
       args: { excludeTypes: 'ns.Container' }
     }
   });
   ```

## Solution 2

Embedding the elements into the container element cause the Manhattan router to ignore the container automatically.

```
container.embed(activity1);
container.embed(activity2);
```

Comment: I have problems defining Container. I haven't used container anywhere in my code so far. I also haven't used joint.dia.Element. I used only joint.dia.Link. When I try to define var Container inside my function initializePaper, exactly before creating this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper...... I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: joint.dia.Element.define is not a function
    at child.initializePaper (main.js:179)
    at child.initializeEditor (main.js:135)
    at child.home (main.js:128)
    at child.execute (backbone.js:1517)..................

Comment: I use Rappid v1.7.2

Comment: I've updated the answer with code compatible with v1.7.2.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed I little bit your code addition for older versions of JointJS/Rappidcode to fit on my local environent and it worked.